# Is there any way to return the value of request field from request class instead of checking validations in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5. If the validation of any field fails, I want to get the value of a particular field from the request class which I have created and it can be displayed in the view class like displaying error messages. Does anyone knows how to code for that?

[image]

above photo, for the id part how to make the syntax to return the value?

**Controller  :**

```
public function edit(Requests\EventRequest1 $request){

    $date=$_POST['eventDate'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $events=EventCal::findOrFail($id);
    $events->update($request->all());
    DB::table('event_cals')
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->update(['title' => $title,'eventDate' => $date]);
    return redirect('/dcalendar');

}
```

**Model :**

```
class EventCal extends Model {

   protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'eventDate',
   ];

}
```

**View :**

```
@if($errors->has('title') )
    <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$id}}</ul></td>
@endif

@if($errors->has('eventDate'))
   <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('eventDate')}}</ul></td>
@endif
```

**EventRequest1(Request Class) :**

```
public function rules()
{


    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',
        'id' => Request::get('id')
    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'title.required' => 'Title is required.',
        'eventDate.after' => 'Event Date is passed.',
        'eventDate.required' => 'Event Date is required.',

    ];
}
```

I want to return the id for view page. In the view page {{$id}} should print the id value.Is there any way? I'm not sure how to return the value of id from request. That's the only thing I needed to know.

Comment: Can you post controller, model and view code?

Comment: I have added the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your request class you must override the `response()` function:

```
public function response(array $errors)
{
       return $this->redirector->back()
       ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
       ->withErrors($errors)
       ->with('id', $this->get('id'));
}
```