# How to use request class to return a value in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel-5

[image]

For the id, I need to return the value of id. The picture in the above is not working. Please can anybody help me?

This the updated one.

```
public function rules()
{


    return [
        'title' => 'required',
        'eventDate' => 'required|date|after:yesterday',

    ];
}

public function messages(){
    return [
        'title.required' => 'Title is required.',
        'eventDate.after' => 'Event Date is passed.',
        'eventDate.required' => 'Event Date is required.',

    ];
}
public function response(array $errors)
{
    return $this->redirector->back()
        ->withInput($this->except($this->dontFlash))
        ->withErrors($errors)
        ->with('id', $this->get('id'));
}
```

Controller

```
public function edit(Requests\EventRequest1 $request){

    $date=$_POST['eventDate'];
    $title=$_POST['title'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $events=EventCal::findOrFail($id);
    $events->update($request->all());
    DB::table('event_cals')
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->update(['title' => $title,'eventDate' => $date]);
    return redirect('/dcalendar');

}
```

view

```
@foreach($events as $evnts)
    {!! Form::open(array('url'=>'ecalendar','method'=>'POST')) !!}
    <table >
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="title" value={!!$evnts->title  !!}> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </td>

            <td><input type="date" name="eventDate" value={!!$evnts->eventDate  !!}> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>


            <td><input type="text" name="id" value={!!$evnts->id  !!}> </td><br>
            <td> <a href="dcalendar/{!!$evnts->eventDate  !!}/{!!$evnts->title  !!}"><input type="button" name="delete" value="Delete"/> </a></td><br>
            <td> <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"/> </td><br>


        @if($errors->has('title'))

                <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$errors->first('title')}} </ul></td>


        @endif
        @if($errors->has('eventDate'))

                <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$id}}</ul></td>



        @endif
        </tr>
        <hr>
    </table>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

Form values will retrieve the value from db. When I am updating values there should be error messages appearing from request class. For the {{$id}} I need the value of id.

Comment: you can not do that. But 5 minutes ago I answered the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/a/35881766/1424329

Comment: Just use the `$id` var sent via `response()` function.

Comment: I have called like this. But exception appear undefined variable id.                                @if($errors->has('title')  )

                    <td><ul class="alert alert-danger" style="width: 250px;height: 40px"> {{$id}} </ul></td>


            @endif

Comment: when I am used {{$errors->id}} instead of  {{$id}}  it will dispaly a [] . But I need to display the value. Here id is the auto incremented column in db

Comment: Are you trying to create form validation rules?

Comment: Yeah. Here I need the value instead of validating

Answer (score 0):

on the top of Class, just type this, your request will work.

`Use Request;`

if you got any error, let us know, also provide your complete FormRequest file code

Comment: Are you saying about first photo? Use Request will underlying an error. Request class code is in above

Comment: What error you getting? and `Request::get('id')` is it loggedin user id ?

Comment: please also share your `routes` controller method for which you are using `Request` and your `form`

Comment: currently how many events you have? do one thing, instead of looping events, just create single event with single form, and try to get values of that. in your request file try to get id by this `$this->id` instead `Request::get('id')` ........ 

tell me one thing, why you have written the form in foreach loop? suppose if there are 1000 events, then it would create 1000 forms, which make no sense. 2nd

Comment: when I put 'id'=>$this->id in rules method it will display an exception as               BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 2615:
Method [validate119] does not exist. There 119 is the id that I needed

Comment: did you tried this one ? `Request::input('id')` on the top of `EventRequest1` class type `use Request;`

Comment: does your 1st problem is solved `Request::input('id');` ? 
try this
`@foreach ($errors->all() as $error) {{ $error }} @endforeach`

Comment: For Request::input('id'); it will not displayed any exceptions. But return [] as the output in view. And for  @foreach ($errors->all() as $error) <li>{{ $error }}</li> endforeach, it will display the validation errors. But not return the value of id. I want the value of id for another purpose.

Comment: Well, I am not getting that what you are going to do. remember, Request class is used for validation purpose. tell me what you are going to do, so I can help you in that sense

Comment: I am displaying all the events forms for editing  and displaying know. So if one validation error occurs it will displayed near all the forms. For avoiding that I need to get that particular id and change the condition of  @if($errors->has('title')) to  @if($errors->has('title') && $evnts->id == {{$id}})  Here, $evnts->id is text box value and {{$id}}) should be the value of id return from request class. Do you get my point?

Comment: Yes, I got your point, but as per my understanding, this is not the proper way. because validation only returns errors not all fields

Comment: Yeah. then there might not be a way to handle this. So better to use one form know.